# Everything gets deleted when I restart my computer

Tags: ubuntu, reboot, xubuntu

I am running xubuntu off of an 8GB USB, and it is partitioned into a 5.5GB, 315Mb and 2.2GB sections.

I install the drivers for my graphics card

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates fglrx-updates-dev
sudo aticonfig --lsa
sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial
```

and then I restart the system

```
sudo reboot
```

However each time I do this, all progress is lost. It doesn't matter what I do, like just adding a txt file `something.txt` or whether I restart it manually. Each time all changes made other then the OS itself are lost.

Why is this happening?

---

Note: I'm running xubuntu - 13.04

Comment: Sounds like your setup the flash drive to be basically a live usb installation.  I would attempt to actually install xubuntu.

Comment: When you made your USB drive bootable you didn't select the option to make it persistent... The only way to fix it is to redo it and make sure you select the option...

Comment: @TheX How do I set persistence? I'm using UNetBootin and its not an option and I cant seem to find it in Disk Utility.

Comment: On the bottom there is a line that says "Space used to perserve files across reboots (Ubuntu only): You put your size in there in MB's 1GB would be 1024MB.

Comment: @TheX I set it to 2000 and it's not working